# will be repaired in x weeks' time: how precise/vague is it?

Tags: meaning-in-context, time

(I have completely rewritten the question in an attempt to make it clearer)

In a certain British English exam, you are given a statement, and must then go through three sentences and choose the one that gives accurate information, according to the original statement.

The original statement is as follows:

> 1) "This road will be closed for repairs from May 1 for 2 weeks."

The sentence that follows is not the correct answer, however I have difficulty explaining exactly why this is not correct:

> 2) "This road will be repaired in two weeks' time beginning on May 1."

What I would like to know is if sentence 2 means the same as:

a) they will start repairing the road in two weeks, beginning on May 1

b) they will have finished repairing the road in two weeks, having begun on May 1

c) both a) and b) are possible

P.S.: If this question is still considered unfit for EL&U, please leave me a comment so I can learn how to further improve this and other questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither (a) nor (b), nor your rewrite, reflects what the original sentence means, which is

> The road will be closed for repairs during the two weeks which begin on May 1—*that is, from May 1 to May 14.*

As for your rewrite:

> This road will be repaired in two weeks' time beginning on May 1.

A native speaker would probably not use the phrase *in two weeks (time)*<sup>✲</sup> in this context. That phrase in futurive contexts usually means “two weeks from **now**”, from the time of utterance. Accordingly, *will be repaired in two weeks* would be parsed with *repaired* taken in a *telic* sense, as expressing a completed action; the entire sentence would be understood to mean “repairs will be finished two weeks from today”, as in your (b).

Adding the phrase *beginning May 1* does not immediately alter this understanding. If you utter the sentence between April 18 and April 30, it will simply imply that repairs will take correspondingly less time. If you utter it on any other date it will confuse the reader or hearer, who will have to puzzle out what you meant to say.

Note, however, that the picture is a bit different if the sentence is cast in the past tense.

> The road was repaired in two weeks.

This will be taken to to mean that repairs occupied the two weeks which began at the Reference Time established in your previous narrative.

> The road was repaired in two weeks beginning on May 1.

This will be taken to mean what you want it to: repairs occupied the two weeks beginning on May 1.

---

<sup>✲</sup> *In two weeks* is always better; *in two weeks' time* adds no nuance of meaning, it's just bureaucratic hyper-precision.

Comment: Actually both sentences, 1 and 2, were taken from an English exam (BrE), which probably explains the 'bureaucratic hyper-precision'.

Comment: @SaraCosta Well, I guess you have to teach people to read bad English, too - there's so much of it!

Answer (score 1):

Sentence two means that they will have finished repairing the road in two weeks' time since May 1, but not necessarily beginning on May 1.